# How to create fade in animation with background color changing from white to cyan on TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have been trying to animate the textfield background color from default color to cyan(fade-in effect), I searched a lot but I am unable to do it.

this is the textfield code

```
physics.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 863, width: 60, height: 30)
    physics.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stringValidation), for: .editingChanged)
    physics.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editValidation), for: .editingChanged)
    physics.keyboardType = .numberPad
    physics.borderStyle = .roundedRect
   scroller1.addSubview(physics)
```

P.S. I have already declared physics variable globally as UITextField and I am using Swift 4

Your time and help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: you try to add animate layer for this

Comment: To add: A "fade" is animation. SO first try to make the background color change - which your code doesn't address. (I'd say you are headed down the *wrong* path but I really don't know what `physics` is with the code you posted.) Once you actually change the background color the way you want, animate that change. (I prefer 0.3 seconds for most animations like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
self.physics.backgroundColor = .red
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5) {
   self.physics.backgroundColor = .cyan
}
```